# How to get the size of zipped folder

Tags: go, zip

Use case is:
I want to zip a folder which could contain n number of files with difference sizes. I want to add limit like if the zip size > x (MB|GB) then do not create the zip and throw error. I tried to get the size of zip file after the zip is created after iterating the folder but not able to do so. Request help here. I am using io.writer to create zip file instead buffer. Sample code is

**Note:** I am able to calculate the size when using "buf := new(bytes.Buffer)" but I want to calculate using io.writer as seen below

filepath - Path to the folder
downloadLimit - the limit I want to set for downloaded zip file. Like zip file size should not be more then 100 MB

```golang
func GetZipFileSize(filepath string, downloadLimit int, w io.Writer) error {
    
    zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(w)

    // List files
    var files []FileAndPath
    var err error
    
    // We have function to fetch files in variable "files" which is used below

    // ZIP files
    for _, file := range files {
        
        // Determine filename in ZIP
        zipFilename := file.Path
        
        filename := fp.Join(SOME_PATH, file.Path)

        // Create ZIP entry
        fileToZip, err := os.Open(filename)
        if err != nil {
            return SOME_ERROR
        }
        info, err := fileToZip.Stat()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        header.Name = zipFilename
        header.Method = zip.Deflate
        writer, err := zipWriter.CreateHeader(header)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // Set content for ZIP entry
        if _, err = io.Copy(writer, fileToZip); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if err = fileToZip.Close(); err != nil {
            // Nothing
        }
    }

    // Wrap-up
    if err := zipWriter.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Above function create zip file, but I want it to stop creation as soon the limit is reached and exit OR at least get the size of the zip file created

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: posted code snippet above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard API does not provide an [`io.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer) implementaion to do that, afaik. It exists a [`LimitReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#LimitReader) but it is of little use for your case and would led us to write rather complex code.

Instead, you can write your own `io.Writer` wrapper implementation to ensure that if the total amount of bytes written onto it exceeds some length, or is about to, return an error.

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    bigBuf := strings.NewReader(strings.Repeat("borng string", 10000))

    dst := &LimitWriter{Writer: os.Stdout, N: 20}

    n, err := io.Copy(dst, bigBuf)
    fmt.Println("n=", n)
    fmt.Println("err=", err)
}

var ErrWriteOverflow = errors.New("write overflow, data is too large")

type LimitWriter struct {
    io.Writer
    N       int64
    written int64
}

func (l *LimitWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if l.written+int64(len(p)) >= l.N {
        return 0, ErrWriteOverflow
    }
    n, err = l.Writer.Write(p)
    l.written += int64(n)
    return
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ktgF-pOzFjm

Comment: Thank you, this helped. Any idea how can we remove the data thats been written to the writer by the time the condition fails  if l.written+int64(len(p)) >= l.N

Comment: It depends of the underlying writer you talk about. You might want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion how you could solve this. Explaination in the code.
I think there is no (easy) way to calculate/estimate the size of a future zip file without executing the actual compression.

Line 1 of the code assumes you already have some kind of byte representation of the file(s) you want to zip.

```
func main() {       

    // Create a buffer to write our archive to (in memory)
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    // Create a new zip archive writer, that writes to our in memory buffer
    archiveWriter := zip.NewWriter(buf)

    // ensure to close your zip writer later
    defer archiveWriter.Close()

    // you probably want to do this in a loop and repeat for each file you want add to the zip archive
    // this is the content of a file you want to zip / instead read it from disk with ioutil.ReadFile() or some other approach
    dummyBytes := []byte("ThisCouldBeTheContentOfYourSourceFile")
    fileWriter, _ := archiveWriter.Create("fileNameOfSourceFileInZip")
    _, _ = fileWriter.Write(dummyBytes)
    
    
    // validate the in memory representation of the zip file does not exceed your limit
    if buf.Len() > 1000 {
        // todo raise error
        return
    }
    
    // write the zip file to the disk, you could ofc also use io.writer
    _ = ioutil.WriteFile("TargetZipFile.zip", buf.Bytes(), 0644)
}
```

Please note that I did not implement any error handling - you probably want to add that.